# Is it possible to execute a method whenever the class is required?

Tags: ruby

I have a class:

```
class foo
   GetActiveWindow = Win32API.new("User32","GetActiveWindow", [], 'L')
   @hwnd = GetActiveWindow.call()
   def baz
       #do stuff with @hwnd
   end
end
```

I think in any usual case the above code would work in the way I need it to. For every instance of the running program, the class will obtain the hwnd of the main window.

However in this case, I'm running the ruby script through an application which is always running such that `require 'foo.rb'` calls `@hwnd = GetActiveWindow.call()` once but never again.

Is there a method like the following:

```
class foo
   GetActiveWindow = Win32API.new("User32","GetActiveWindow", [], 'L')
   def baz
       #do stuff with @hwnd
   end
   def onrequire()
       @hwnd = GetActiveWindow.call()
   end
end
```

I know you can define an `initialise()` method which is called whenever `class.new()` is called, however in the case of this application it doesn't really make 'sense' to call the method `new`, if that makes sense... So I was wondering if I could easily shortcut it.

Comment: _"the above code would work"_ – did you try it?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You don't require classes, you require files. What do you mean by "when a class is required"? There is no such thing in Ruby as requiring a class.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Okay. When you require a file which contains a class. I'm 99% certain that you understood that much, and that it was implied...

Comment: @Stefan I have no application to try it in, exclusively, but I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work for single instance scripts, whereby each script runs in its own instance of ruby. The problem here being that the application I am running the ruby scripts in, does not sandbox them. So a file required in the application is only every required 1 across all scripts.

Comment: @Sancarn I asked because you declare an instance variable in the class body. This variable would be available to class methods but not to instance methods, i.e. `@hwnd` would be `nil` within `baz`.

Comment: Oh really? That is very odd because if I do that in the application I am running the ruby scripts from `@hwnd` is not nil in `baz` which strikes me as rather bizarre... I guess the ruby interpreter is doing something funky with the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant `Foo` and not `foo` as the latter is an invalid constant name in Ruby.

No, there is no such callback for `require` in classes. Require just loads and parses a file and there is no direct relation between a class and a file (though it is common to have the `Foo` class in `foo.rb`). There could be more than one class in a file, none, or one that does not match the filename.

You can either assign the handle in the initializer, as you already have found out (though I did not understand why you don't like the approach:

```
def initialize()
  @hwnd = GetActiveWindow.call()
end
```

or add a method which `memoizes` the handle

```
def hwnd
  @hwnd ||= GetActiveWindow.call()
end
```

**Update after comment of OP:**

So all this class is suposed to do is obtaining a handle. And you do not want to instantiate it. Also it does not have any state. Then I suppose you make this a class with class-methods:

```
class Foo
  def self.handle
     ...
  end
end
```

and call it like this

```
Foo.handle
```

Comment: My main issue against using `initialize` is rather subjective. But I would commonly expect `ProgressBar.new()` to create a new progress bar. Where as, in this case, it simply gets the handles to already existing windows of the application. Perhaps if I named the class `ProgressBarHelper` it'd sound better...

Comment: I guess this is indeed the best solution. I am always concerned about speed but perhaps that concern is misplaced.

Comment: I don't think that instantiating one more object will matter. 
Unless you've measured the various solutions I'd not optimize. I'd rather optimize for clean/testable/concise code.
Class methods are harder to refactor and test, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Just create `handle` accessor and use itself whenever you want hwnd.

```
class Foo
   GetActiveWindow = Win32API.new("User32","GetActiveWindow", [], 'L')

   def baz
     # do stuff with handle
     PostMessage(handle, ...)
   end

   def handle
     @hwnd ||= GetActiveWindow.call()
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to call the method on `require` then you can simply move the `onrequire` call outside of the class:

```
# foo.rb
class Foo
   GetActiveWindow = Win32API.new("User32","GetActiveWindow", [], 'L')
   def baz
       #do stuff with @hwnd
   end
   def self.on_require
       @hwnd = GetActiveWindow.call()
   end
end

Foo.on_require
```

In this case, the last line is ran on `require`. You'll obviously have to structure your class / instance methods to accommodate what you're trying to do, but this example will get you there.

Comment: You can just add the `@hwnd =` part to the class body, will do the same thing.